# Stubbing I18next useTranslation hook in Jest doesn't trigger toHaveBeenCalled

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, i18next

I'm trying to stub/spy the translation, not just mock it, and I can't seem to get it to trigger even in this most base case.

```js
/**
 * ComponentName.jsx
 */

import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export default function ComponentName() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return <div>t(`index:path`)</div>
}

/**
 * ComponentName.test.jsx
 */

import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import ComponentName from "./ComponentName";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
  useTranslation: () => ({ t: jest.fn(key => key) })
}));

it("calls the translation function", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<ComponentName />);

  expect(useTranslation().t).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

When I drop a `console.log(t)` in the `ComponentName.jsx file`, it correctly displays that it's a mocked function.
If I put `t()` in the `ComponentName.test.jsx` file, it passes.

Is there a way to stub this so that I can eventually tag it with `toHaveBeenCalledWith`? Or am I relegated to doing `contains("index:path")` on the component?

---

Edit: So, when I updated on @felixmosh's answer

```js
/**
 * ComponentName.test.jsx
 */


import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';

describe('<SomeComponent />', () => {
  it('dispatches SORT_TABLE', () => {
    const i18nextMock = {
      t: jest.fn(key => key),
    };
    const enzymeWrapper = mount(
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18nextMock}>
        <SomeComponent />
      </I18nextProvider>
    );

    expect(i18nextmock.t).toHaveBeenCalled()
  });
});

/**
 * ComponentName.jsx
 */

import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export default function ComponentName() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return <div>t(`index:path`)</div>
}
```

It's the same issue. If `t` was `"a string"` instead of `jest.fn()`, when i console.log `t` in `ComponentName.jsx`, I correctly get `"a string"`, when I console.log `t` as `jest.fn(key => key)`, I correctly get a function.

But when I call it, I don't get it.

Is it possible that it's not the same instance that's being sent to I18nextProvider?

Answer (score 4):

2 Things that you should improve in your code:

1. `useTransaltion` is a hook which requires `context`, make sure you wrap you component with `i18nextProvider`.
2. As of the fact you will have nested components switch `shallow` with `mount`.
3. There is no need for mocking anything, `i18next` has a built-it support of tests.
   In order to enable it use [`cimode`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage) as the `lng` when configuring your `i18next` for **tests**.

```
// i18nForTests.js

import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  lng: 'cimode',
  // ----- ^
  // have a common namespace used around the full app
  ns: ['translations'],
  defaultNS: 'translations',

  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false, // not needed for react!!
  },

  resources: { en: { translations: {} } },
});

export default i18n;
```

```js
// SomeComponent.test.js
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from '../i18nForTests';

describe('<SomeComponent />', () => {
  it('dispatches SORT_TABLE', () => {
    const enzymeWrapper = mount(
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
          <SomeComponent />
        </I18nextProvider>
    );
    enzymeWrapper.find('.sort').simulate('click');

    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('#some-text').text()).toEqual('MY_TRANS_KEY');
  });
});
```

Edit: Version with mocked I18next

```js
// i18nextMock.js
export const i18nextMock = {
  t: jest.fn(),
  // Do the same for other i18next fields
};

// SomeComponent.test.js
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18nextMock from '../i18nextMock';

describe('<SomeComponent />', () => {
  it('dispatches SORT_TABLE', () => {
    const enzymeWrapper = mount(
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18nextMock}>
          <SomeComponent />
        </I18nextProvider>
    );
    enzymeWrapper.find('.sort').simulate('click');

    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('#some-text').text()).toEqual('MY_TRANS_KEY');
  });
});
```

Comment: How do you configure your `lng` for jest?

Comment: I mean, yes, I understand that's a possibility, but I'm not asking to figure out if the result is correct, but that the translation method itself is called with the correct values by spying on it.

Comment: Basically I'm ensuring that `t()` is called with the correct parameters, not that the result is correct, even though the result is the parameter. Example:

I could literally just put `MY_TRANS_KEY` as the content of `#some-text`, and it would pass, and that's where the issue lies, I'm trying to remove that ambiguity.

Comment: In that case, pass `mocked` i18n to the I18nextProvider, check the edited code