# next-i18next unit testing error 'Cannot read property language of undefined' with Link and jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, i18next, next-i18next

`next-i18next` uses it's own `Link` component to be compatible with locale sub-paths.

https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next

When I try a simple snapshot test I get the error `Cannot read property language of undefined`.

My component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TFunction } from 'next-i18next';
import { withTranslation, Link } from '../../../i18n';

interface HeaderProps {
  readonly t: TFunction;
}

const Header = ({ t }: HeaderProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      <Flex>
        <Box>
          <Link href="/">{t('home')}</Link>
        </Box>
      </Flex>
    </>
  );
};

export default withTranslation('common')(Header);
```

It's snapshot test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Header from './Header';

describe('<Header/>', () => {
  test('it should render correctly', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Header />);
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The test runs and passes without the `Link` component as expected.

I have defined my `i18n.ts` as follows:

```
import path from 'path';
import NextI18Next from 'next-i18next';
import { publicRuntimeConfig } from './next.config';

const { localeSubpaths } = publicRuntimeConfig;

export const nextI18next = new NextI18Next({
  browserLanguageDetection: false,
  defaultNS: 'common',
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  otherLanguages: ['fr'],
  localeSubpaths,
  localePath: path.resolve('./public/static/locales'),
});

export const {
  i18n,
  appWithTranslation,
  Link,
  withTranslation,
  Router,
} = nextI18next;
```

Is there anyway I can fix this error?

Comment: Have you figured it out @RyanP13 ?

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your component under test with i18nextProvider.

Check [Stubbing I18next useTranslation hook in Jest doesn't trigger toHaveBeenCalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036604/stubbing-i18next-usetranslation-hook-in-jest-doesnt-trigger-tohavebeencalled/64068566#64068566)

**Edit**
I18next has a "special" languages (`cimode`) which makes the `t` function always return the given key, this way in tests you can assert on the key instead of the value (which can be changed, sometimes not by the developer).

Comment: This didn't help me. Can you share more info on this `language` property?

Comment: If it matters I am on Next.js 9.5.4.

Comment: Yes, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'language' of undefined"
It shows for both page components and regular React components when they have Link imported from i18n. No problem if Link is commented out, test can identify other translation keys used in the view. I would appreciate some hints on what to debug next.

Comment: Did you wrapped your Component under test with the i18nextProvider?

Comment: I used a custom render function (https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-intl#creating-a-custom-render-function), tried both I18NextProvider (locale not passed as a prop) and IntlProvider (passing locale='en') with the same results.

Comment: Since your are using next-i18next, try to wrap with `withAppTranslation`, (https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/blob/a538ad4b4fb9357c36b189849e351190ed138013/src/hocs/app-with-translation.tsx)

Comment: Already doing it. Otherwise I believe the translations would not work in browser (i.e. compiled). It's just the <Link> component in test environment that's causing troubles.

Comment: You need to do it in the test env, since you are rendering your component outside of next

Comment: Suddenly the test started passing after I removed "/__mocks__/react-i18next.js". Lol. I guess there was some contexts conflict. Need to understand now where the stubs are coming for useTranslation and others. Thanks for assistance!

Answer (score 0):

For every one who can't get why this error is exist: **check your locale files is correct** and doesn't content special symbols out of quotes