# next-i18next Jest Testing with useTranslation

Tags: jestjs, next.js, react-i18next, next-i18next

Testing libs...always fun.  I am using `next-i18next` within my NextJS project.  We are using the `useTranslation` hook with namespaces.

When I run my test there is a warning:

> console.warn
> react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next

```
> 33 |   const { t } = useTranslation(['common', 'account']);
     |                 ^
```

---

I have tried the setup from the [react-i18next test examples](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/test-jest) without success. I have tried [this suggestion too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036604/stubbing-i18next-usetranslation-hook-in-jest-doesnt-trigger-tohavebeencalled/64068566#64068566).

as well as just trying to mock `useTranslation` without success.

Is there a more straightforward solution to avoid this warning?  The test passes FWIW...

```
test('feature displays error', async () => {
    const { findByTestId, findByRole } = render(
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <InviteCollectEmails onSubmit={jest.fn()} />
      </I18nextProvider>,
      {
        query: {
          orgId: 666,
        },
      }
    );

    const submitBtn = await findByRole('button', {
      name: 'account:organization.invite.copyLink',
    });

    fireEvent.click(submitBtn);

    await findByTestId('loader');

    const alert = await findByRole('alert');
    within(alert).getByText('failed attempt');
  });
```

Last, is there a way to have the translated plain text be the outcome, instead of the namespaced: `account:account:organization.invite.copyLink`?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: no...i might look into https://github.com/vinissimus/next-translate

Comment: How about now? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 16):

Use the following snippet before the describe block OR in beforeEach() to mock the needful.

```
jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
    useTranslation: () => ({ t: key => key }),
}));
```

Hope this helps. Peace.

Comment: For me, it just worked placing it before the describe() blog.

Comment: Yeah, putting this to "beforeAll" or other hooks wont do the trick, but what the other comment said did it for me

Comment: I put it in my `jest.setup.js`, also I changed the mock for the t function slightly, to accept params: `t: (key, parameters) => (parameters ? key + JSON.stringify(parameters) : key),`

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to make the tests work with an instance of i18next using the `renderHook` function and the `useTranslation` hook from `react-i18next` based on the previous answers and some research.

This is the Home component I wanted to test:

```js
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

const Home = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation("");
  return (
    <main>
      <div>
        <h1> {t("welcome", {ns: 'home'})}</h1>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
};

export default Home;
```

First, we need to create a setup file for jest so we can start an i18n instance and import the translations to the configuration. `test/setup.ts`

```js
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

import homeES from '@/public/locales/es/home.json';
import homeEN from '@/public/locales/en/home.json';

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  lng: "es",
  resources: {
    en: {
      home: homeEN,
    },
    es: {
      home: homeES,
    }
  },
  fallbackLng: "es",
  debug: false,
});

export default i18n;
```

Then we add the setup file to our `jest.config.js`:

```js
setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/test/setup.ts"]
```

Now we can try our tests using the `I18nextProvider` and the `useTranslation` hook:

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { cleanup, render, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { I18nextProvider, useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

import Home from '.';

describe("Index page", (): void => {
  afterEach(cleanup);

  it("should render properly in Spanish", (): void => {
    const t = renderHook(() => useTranslation());

    const component = render( 
      <I18nextProvider i18n={t.result.current.i18n}>
        <Home / >
      </I18nextProvider>
    );

    expect(component.getByText("Bienvenido a Pocky")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("should render properly in English", (): void => {
    const t = renderHook(() => useTranslation());
    act(() => {
      t.result.current.i18n.changeLanguage("en");
    });

    const component = render( 
      <I18nextProvider i18n={t.result.current.i18n}>
        <Home/>
      </I18nextProvider>
    );
    expect(component.getByText("Welcome to Pocky")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

});
```

Here we used the `I18nextProvider` and send the i18n instance using the useTranslation hook. after that the translations were loaded without problems in the Home component.

We can also change the selected language running the `changeLanguage()` function and test the other translations.

Answer (score 1):

use this for replace render function.

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import DarkModeToggleBtn from '../../components/layout/DarkModeToggleBtn'
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next'
import { NextRouter } from 'next/router'


jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
    I18nextProvider: jest.fn(),
    __esmodule: true,
 }))

  
const createProps = (locale = 'en', router: Partial<NextRouter> = {}) => ({
    pageProps: {
        _nextI18Next: {
        initialLocale: locale,
        userConfig: {
            i18n: {
            defaultLocale: 'en',
            locales: ['en', 'fr'],
            },
        },
        },
    } as any,
    router: {
        locale: locale,
        route: '/',
        ...router,
    },
} as any)

const Component = appWithTranslation(() => <DarkModeToggleBtn />)

const defaultRenderProps = createProps()

const renderComponent = (props = defaultRenderProps) => render(
    <Component {...props} />
)


describe('', () => {
    it('', () => {

        renderComponent()
     
        expect(screen.getByRole("button")).toHaveTextContent("")

    })
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I used a little bit more sophisticated approach than mocking to ensure all the functions work the same both in testing and production environment.

First, I create a testing environment:

```tsx
// testing/env.ts
import i18next, { i18n } from "i18next";
import JSDomEnvironment from "jest-environment-jsdom";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

declare global {
  var i18nInstance: i18n;
}

export default class extends JSDomEnvironment {
  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    /* The important part start */
    const i18nInstance = i18next.createInstance();
    await i18nInstance.use(initReactI18next).init({
      lng: "cimode",
      resources: {},
    });
    this.global.i18nInstance = i18nInstance;
    /* The important part end */
  }
}
```

I add this environment in `jest.config.ts`:

```tsx
// jest.config.ts
export default {
  // ...
  testEnvironment: "testing/env.ts",
};
```

Sample component:

```tsx
// component.tsx
import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";

export const Component = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return <div>{t('foo')}</div>
}
```

And later on I use it in tests:

```tsx
// component.test.tsx
import { setI18n } from "react-i18next";
import { create, act, ReactTestRenderer } from "react-test-renderer";
import { Component } from "./component";

it("renders Component", () => {
  /* The important part start */
  setI18n(global.i18nInstance);
  /* The important part end */
  let root: ReactTestRenderer;
  act(() => {
    root = create(<Component />);
  });
  expect(root.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who couldn't find a solution or any help in the library itself, this is what I ended up doing to actually load the translations and test them.

I'm using Next JS v12.x and next-i18next v12.1.0 along with jest and testing-library but could be applied to other environments.

1. I added a testing utility file src/utils/testing.ts

```js
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import { DEFAULT_LOCALE } from 'src/utils/constants';

/**
 * Initializes the i18n instance with the given namespaces.
 * @param {string[]} namespaces - An array of namespaces.
 * @param {string} locale - The locale to use.
 * @returns {i18n.i18n} The initialized i18n instance.
 */
const initializeI18n = async (
  namespaces: string[],
  locale = DEFAULT_LOCALE
) => {
  const resources: { [ns: string]: object } = {};

  // Load resources for the default language and given namespaces
  namespaces.forEach((ns) => {
    const filePath = `public/locales/${locale}/${ns}.json`;
    try {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires,global-require,import/no-dynamic-require
      const translations = require(`../../${filePath}`);
      resources[ns] = translations;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(
        `Could not load translations for locale: ${locale}, namespace: ${ns}`
      );
    }
  });

  await i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    lng: locale,
    fallbackLng: locale,
    debug: false,
    ns: namespaces,
    defaultNS: namespaces[0],
    resources: { [locale]: resources },
    interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
  });

  return i18n;
};

export default initializeI18n;
```

2. On my test file I asynchronously initialized the instance with the namespace I wanted to load, rendered my component and awaited for the screen to find the rendered translated text.

```js
describe('when price is zero', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await initializeI18n(['common_areas']);

    render(<CommonAreaCard commonArea={mockCommonArea(0)} />);
  });

  it('should render the free price', async () => {
    expect(
      await screen.findByText('Sin costo de reservación')
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing the following:
Add this to your `package.json`

```
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": [
    "./jestSetupFile.js"
  ]
}
```

Then add this in `jestSetupFile.js`

```
jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
  useTranslation: () => {
    return {
      t: (str) => str,
    };
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last question, I found a way to convert namespace to its actual translated value. For some reason wrapping the provider never worked for me hence I had to look into this new alternative.

The original mock by the documentation:

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
 
  useTranslation: () => {
    return {
      t: (str) => str,
      i18n: {
        changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {}),
      },
    };
  },
  initReactI18next: {
    type: '3rdParty',
    init: () => {},
  }
}));
```

We'll need to somehow convert t(str) => str to return the translated value rather than the namespace. Take note it returns a string. So we have to somehow convert, for example, "button.proceed" to englishFile["button"]["proceed"]. By doing this, it will return the translated value.

This function does just that.

```
const translate = (givenString, file) => {

const splitArr = givenString.split(".");
let result = file;
for (let i = 0; i < splitArr.length; i++) {
    result = result[splitArr[i]];
}
    return result;
};
```

And now, the new mock should look something like this,

```
jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
    useTranslation: () => {
        // translation files should be placed here to avoid error warnings.
        const enFile = jest.requireActual("../../locales/en.json");
        return {
            t: (key) => translate(key, enFile),
            i18n: {
                changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {}),
            },
        };
    },
    initReactI18next: {
        type: "3rdParty",
        init: () => {},
    },
    I18nextProvider: ({ children }) => children,
}));
```