# Mock t function from i18next to make it return value by keys

Tags: jestjs, i18next

I need to mock `i18next` and `useTranslation` hook, which contains `t` function that has to return values by provided keys, but I didn't find a way I can do that.

```js
//Here I import my translation file
import mockTranslations from './src/locales/en/translation.json';

...

// Mock react-i18next
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-i18next'),
  useTranslation: () => ({
    //Here I want to get translations, but it just returns an empty string
    t: (key: string) => mockTranslations[key],
    i18n: {
      language: 'en',
      addResourceBundle: () => jest.fn(),
      changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {}),
    },
  }),
}));
```

So, I want to get translation value by key. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you expand on _"doesn't work"_? I'd be inclined to test with `t: (key: string): string => key`, rather than coupling the low-level tests to the actual translations, otherwise your tests are either: 1. often getting broken as the translations are reviewed and updated; or 2. filled with `expect(text).toBe(mockTranslations[expectedKey])` (in which case you might as well `expect(text).toBe(expectedKey)`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe so, my solution returns just an empty string. Why I need normal translation, not just a key? I have a libraries that have to get raw translation (not just a key) to work properly

Comment: Have you tried these solutions? the second answer seems to be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66973857/next-i18next-jest-testing-with-usetranslation/77170853#77170853

Comment: @Mister_CK thanks! Found it useful and was able to find solution using this answer

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the way how I could do it and share it with you. In comments I got answer using this link ([next-i18next Jest Testing with useTranslation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66973857/next-i18next-jest-testing-with-usetranslation/77170853#77170853)), but I had to get how it could work with TypeScript and found this one line solution.

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-i18next'),
  useTranslation: () => {
    const enFile = jest.requireActual('./src/locales/en/translation.json');
    return {
      t: (stringKey: string) =>
        stringKey.split('.').reduce((result, key) => result[key], enFile),
      i18n: {
        language: 'en',
        addResourceBundle: () => jest.fn(),
        changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {}),
      },
    };
  },
}));
```

Hope it helps